# How to update jsonView of an element?

Tags: javascript, django

I have Json objects which I want to pretty print using jsonView.
But everytime I try to update the same element with new Json object it remembers the old objects as well and pretty prints the all the old ones as well as the new one.

I am using the following command to pretty print.

```
function commandPopup(){
  $('.commandPopup').click(function()
  {
    $(".modal-title").html($(this).attr('box')+":"+$(this).attr('task'));
    $('#commandPopup').on('show', function ()
    {
      $('.modal-body',this).css({width:'auto',height:'auto', 'max-height':'100%'});
    });
    $("#commandPopup").modal('show');
    $.getJSON('get_taskinfo',
    {
      'box' : $(this).attr('box'),
      'task' : $(this).attr('task')
    }).done(function(data)
    {
      console.log(data);
     var config=data.config;
     $("#config").jsonView(config);
    });
  });
}
```

---

Answer (score 0):

I just solved it by clearing the #config id with before adding the json object to it.

```
$("#config").html("");
$("#config").jsonView(config);
```